# DisplayMemberPath of telerik GridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: silverlight-4.0, telerik, radgridview

I have a telerik gridview

```
<UserControl x:Class="TelerikGridViewComboBoxExample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="143*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="157*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Good Sample"/>
            <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="radGridView"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Peoples}">
                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                    <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn 
                    DataMemberBinding="{Binding CountryID}"
                    UniqueName="Country"
                    SelectedValueMemberPath="Id"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>

                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" UniqueName="First Name"/>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" UniqueName="Last Name"/>
                </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            </telerik:RadGridView>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and here is a xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Telerik.Windows.Controls;

namespace TelerikGridViewComboBoxExample
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
        }

        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var x in
               new People[] {
                new People { CountryID = 0, FirstName = "Sebastain", LastName = "Vettel" },
                new People { CountryID = 1, FirstName = "Fernando", LastName = "Alonso" },
                new People { CountryID = 2, FirstName = "James", LastName = "Button" }
                })
            {
                Peoples.Add(x);
            }


            foreach (var x in
            new Country[] {
                new Country { Id = 0, Name = "Germany",Nationality = "german"},
                new Country { Id = 1, Name = "Spain" ,Nationality = "Spanish"},
                new Country { Id = 2, Name = "UK" ,Nationality = "English"}
                })
            {
                Countries.Add(x);
            }

            this.DataContext = this;
            ((GridViewComboBoxColumn)this.radGridView.Columns["Country"]).ItemsSource = Countries;
        }

        private ObservableCollection<People> peoples = new ObservableCollection<People>();
        public ObservableCollection<People> Peoples
        {
            get { return peoples; }
            set { peoples = value; }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Country> countries = new ObservableCollection<Country>();
        public ObservableCollection<Country> Countries
        {
            get { return countries; }
            set { countries = value; }
        }
    }

    public class People
    {
        public int CountryID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Country
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Nationality { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Everything works ok, but I want to display in countries column value Nationality, but as now I want in combo names of countries to choose.

so :
1. user clicks at row in Country column ,
2. selects Germany
3.value in row is Germnan.

if it is not possilbe, I want to have in that row first, and last letter of name of country(for example "gy")

I'm using 2010.1.603.1040 version of telerik silverlight pack.

Is it possible?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

use switch case with using row command by including a custom field(button) in the gridview code and pass record id(from db) as the argument
google "row command in .net" for just syntax
then you can perform whatever action you wish to perform